# Handling pull-requests across parallel forks sharing a parent

Tags: git, github, pull-request, cherry-pick

I have the following situation (`repo` had no activity in the last year):

```
 repo _
       |
       |_ Fork_1
       |_ Fork_2 ... commit_4 ... commit_5 ... commit_6
       |    
       |_ Fork_my ... commit_12 ... commit_13...
```

I'd like to get `commit_4` and `commit_6` from `Fork_2` into my fork (`Fork_my`). What I've done previously, but I feel is not the right approach:

1. Create a branch from `Fork_my:main` (my repo:branch name) e.g.: `new_merge`
2. Create a pull request  `new_merge` <- `Fork_2`
3. Resolve conflicts in Github desktop
4. Create a new branch with resolved conflicts e.g.: `new_merge_final`
5. Pull request `Fork_my:main` <- `new_merge_final` (or swap `new_merge_final` for `main` and rename)

I'm looking into `cherry-pick`-ing but still unsure of the workflow.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out:

```
- create new branch from Fork_my:main - e.g. new_branch
- terminal switch to branch


- git remote -v 

# f_2 is new remote alias
- git remote add f_2 https://github.com/Fork_2_user/Fork_2.git

- git remote -v 
- git fetch f_2  / git fetch --all

# make sure you're back on the branch you want to cherry-pick to

- git status
# shaXXXX are found on the commits (e.g. commit_4, commit_6 as per above scenario)
- git cherry-pick shaXXXX
- git cherry-pick shaXXXX2
...
- git cherry-pick shaXXXXN


# on conflict in terminal - open VS code and resolve by replacing the entire section from <<<<<<< to >>>>>>> (including the <<<<<<< and >>>>>>>) with the correct END-result. Then save the file and return to the command prompt.

# after the above:
 
- git add .

# --no-edit keeps the same commit message, otherwise VIM is opened

- git cherry-pick --continue --no-edit

# START next few lines of code only necessary if changes were made on origin during the cherry-pick process
- git fetch origin

- git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/new_branch

- git pull

# END above few lines of code only necessary if changes were made on origin during the cherry-pick process

- git push -u origin new_branch
```